# Same layout, different content using tiles

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, templates, jsp

What is the best way to go about templating a site with tiles or jsp's so that I can manage to have one layout but many many pages of different content / data.

I'm a beginner at Eclipse and trying to get this site up fast, so I'm looking for the easiest / fastest solution. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way of building Java Web Application is I think [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo). It's lot like Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend sitemesh v2 (v3 currently in alpha).. simple concept, simple to configure and simple to start developing with..

http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/